# php looping from list

Tags: php, loops

I am making a script. And in this script i will supply some keyword list. And then it will go to a targeted site and grabbing data. 
Please take a look to my code :

```
//my option start
$toplist=file_get_contents('http://mysite/list.txt');

//list grabbing

$listgrabbing=explode('target="_',$toplist);
$counting=count($listgrabbing);
$l='0';
for ($l=0 ; $l <=$counting ; $l++){
$targetsite='http://targetsite/search?q='.$listgrabbing;
$revip=file_get_contents($targetsite);

//Rest of code
```

now see, i have some keyword lists, in a txt file. . Such as :

```
football
cricket
basketball
chase
```

and my code will take first keyword and search into target site and grab. And then second,third,forth... 
But it is not select keyword from list. What is the error here ?

Comment: Don't you need to be using `explode("\r\n",$toplist)`

Comment: @Bonzo ,Will you please  clarify it.

Comment: `$l='0'` then using that $l in a for loop smacks of cargo-cult programming.

Comment: What does the text file look like?

Comment: @Bonzo , similar this one :  http://digitalfinance.info/list.txt

Comment: What exactly does `$toplist` look like  ??

Comment: `"\r\n"` should be a new line. If not just try `"\n"`

Comment: try `.../search?q='.$listgrabbing[$l];`. note the `[$l]`.

Comment: @air4x , Thanks for your nice suggestion . 
Also it is solved by Bonzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$toplist=file_get_contents('http://mysite/list.txt');
$listgrabbing=explode("\n",$toplist);
foreach($listgrabbing as $item){
     $targetsite='http://targetsite/search?q='.$item;
     $revip=file_get_contents($targetsite);
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem on my list ?
I think so, because, i have used this. But it is not taking the keywords.

Comment: Yes, i am sure it is problem in keywords. 
because i have checked with a single keyword, and it's working.

Comment: then how should i write the list ?

Comment: Just like the [http://digitalfinance.info/list.txt](http://digitalfinance.info/list.txt), I've uploaded an example using that file here [https://bonzodanddcouk.fatcow.com/mine/trial.php](https://bonzodanddcouk.fatcow.com/mine/trial.php)

Comment: Thanks, It is now completed. Actually it is problem in "/n"
. Now fixed with your code. Thanks Again.